# Best way to redirect from one site to new site adding a querystring to it

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I am trying to redirect with .htaccess from one site to another.

However I want to add a querystring to the end of the URL that the redirect takes the person to. I have read lots of articles on here and they are about passing the querystring along to the new site, I just want to ADD a querystring (a promo code) to the rule.

Something like:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.com$ [OR]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$
       RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/subscribe.aspx?code=xxke [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled.

Any ideas

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ":" and "?" may be special characters in format strings consider escaping them as follows:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ https\://www.newsite.com/subscribe.aspx\?code=xxke [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yes worked mate cheers didnt think you had to escape the 2nd part of htaccess rules for some reason